# ./xsum: Permission denied make: *** [xsum.out] Error 126

Tags: macos, makefile, permission-denied

I  am trying to insall f2c/f77 compiler on mac osx using the instructions given http://www.webmo.net/support/fortran_osx.html and I get the following error :

```
./xsum: Permission denied 
 make: *** [xsum.out] Error 126
```

please help , as in installation it misses to create : /usr/local/bin/f2c

I followed the folowing :

```
chmod +x install_f2c_osx.csh
sudo ./install_f2c_osx.csh
```

PS : the install_f2c_osx.csh contains the following code :

```
`#! /bin/csh
setenv INSTALL /usr/local
curl "http://netlib.sandia.gov/cgi-bin/netlib/netlibfiles.tar?filename=netlib/f2c" -o       "f2c.tar"
tar -xvf f2c.tar
gunzip -rf f2c/*
cd f2c
mkdir libf2c
mv libf2c.zip libf2c
cd libf2c
unzip libf2c.zip
cp makefile.u Makefile
make
cp f2c.h $INSTALL/include
cp libf2c.a $INSTALL/lib
cd ../src
cp makefile.u Makefile
make
cp f2c $INSTALL/bin
cd ..
mkdir -p $INSTALL/share/man/man1
cp f2c.1t $INSTALL/share/man/man1
cp fc $INSTALL/bin/f77
chmod +x $INSTALL/bin/f77
cd ..
rm -rf f2c
echo "==================SUMMARY=================="
echo $0 " has built and installed:"
find $INSTALL -name '*f2c*' -mmin -5
find $INSTALL -name '*f77*' -mmin -5
```

Comment: xsum is like an original version of md5 or other hash checker.  nice script, i haven't used csh in years so i chopped it up for bash on osx. and i don't like redefining f77 as a script file, it bombs on too many times with cmake or configure.

Answer (score 1):

For me, @Steele's solution didn't work. Just to document this here: the second solution posted on Superuser actually worked for me, i.e. my `xsum` binary was not useable by the system, for some reason. In that case, delete the `xsum` binary that came with f2c and build your own using the xsum.c source. That is, edit the initial code to be:

```
#! /bin/csh
setenv INSTALL /usr/local
curl "http://netlib.sandia.gov/cgi-bin/netlib/netlibfiles.tar?filename=netlib/f2c" -o "f2c.tar"
tar -xvf f2c.tar
gunzip -rf f2c/*
cd f2c
mkdir libf2c
mv libf2c.zip libf2c
cd libf2c
unzip libf2c.zip
cp makefile.u Makefile
make
cp f2c.h $INSTALL/include
cp libf2c.a $INSTALL/lib
cd ../src
cp makefile.u Makefile  
rm xsum                 #Added
cc -O xsum.c -o xsum    #Added
chmod +x xsum           #Added
make
cp f2c $INSTALL/bin
cd ..
mkdir -p $INSTALL/share/man/man1
cp f2c.1t $INSTALL/share/man/man1
cp fc $INSTALL/bin/f77
chmod +x $INSTALL/bin/f77
cd ..
rm -rf f2c
echo "==================SUMMARY=================="
echo $0 " has built and installed:"
find $INSTALL -name '*f2c*' -mmin -5
find $INSTALL -name '*f77*' -mmin -5
```